# Delete lines in several files in a folder once (avoid infinite loop)

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have several files in one folder, and I want to delete the first lines in all of them. If I do this:

```
sed -i.bak '1,2000d' *.dat
```

the first 2000 lines are deleted, but then the filename is still of the form `*.dat` and the next 2000 lines are deleted as well, and so on until the file is empty. How can I fix this? Preferably without a complicated script? There are too many files to just list all the file names, they are too complicated to type them all.

Comment: Is that really the _exact_ command you run? That won't get into an infinite loop. You misunderstand how `*.dat` is dealt with. It is expanded only once, before the command is run so there's no way it can cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a for loop, so the command is executed for every file exactly once:

```
for file in *.dat; do sed -i.bak '1,2000d' "$file"; done
```

Notice, `-i.bak` backs up the original file with `.bak` ending.

Comment: Thanks! That looks much better. But what does `file in *` and `$file` stand for? I don't know how to use it in my case, don't quite understand the syntax.

Comment: @Apatura sry I corrected it, i meant `file in *.dat`, It means loop trough all files that match the given pattern in the current working directory, inside the loop that filename is accessible by the variable `$file`. I could also write `for blub in *.dat` and access the file with the variable `$blub`

Comment: Thanks! This works because my solution looks for matching files anew with every step, while `for [...]` looks first which parts match, and then follows that list, right?

Comment: @Apatura actually, I don't understand why your solution does not work, because the `*.dat` part is (or should be) expanded *before* the sed command is called. So it should also work. In your case sed is called once, in my case it is called once for each file.

Comment: I just noticed that your solution still doesn't seem to work. Because of `-i.bak` the shortened file is written in the original file name (which is good for my problem), so the file is different than in the beginning but still matches `*.dat` - so maybe that is why the `for`-loop catches those files again and again.. do I really need to change the file name and delete the original file to avoid this?

Comment: @Apatura `*.dat` doesn't match any `.bak` file, even if it's `.dat.bak`. So like I said both solutions should work. I also tried your solution and for me it worked as desired; no endless loop.